# Solution to grab text from page and display it elsewhere?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a solution how to grab a text from one part of the page to be displayed on a different part of the same page (not stored).

To explain this easier. I have this:

```
<div id="test"> hello world </div>
```

I want to grab the text "hello world" and display it somewhere else on the website as well.

Im thinking that there might be a javascript code that could grab that **specific div text**?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: When you say "somewhere else" do you mean just visually or elsewhere in the DOM?

Comment: I mean within the creation of human kind. Darin just assisted me with this, cheers guys :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
```

and to place it on some other part of the page:

```
<div id="otherpart"></div>
```

you could set the innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById('otherpart').innerHTML = text;
```